# Imported dialog track distorting

Tags: dialogue, importing, pro-tools, distortion

I just imported the dialog audio from the QT video of this clip and for some reason the clip gets really distorted, but sounds fine on the actual QT video. I imported other SFX files into the session and they come out just fine. This is what the waveform (stereo) looks like: http://instagr.am/p/hz8UK/

What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

I've had issues importing the audio from a QT into PT before where the audio is fine when playing the video in QT but when I import, only one channel is at the wrong sample rate playing at half speed but the other tracks from the QT are fine.

Not sure if this will work for you, but the work around I did was in QT pro, export the QT video as an AIFF or WAV with the proper session settings.  For whatever reason, this fixed my issue of the single track importing into PT at the wrong speed.  This may help with your audio if it's fine on the QT but distorted on PT import.

Comment: @GaryMegregian Is there any other way than QT pro? I only have the standard QT. Should I invest in QT pro? 

Comment: Never mind got it exporting the audio out of FCP. I'm not sure what the if they even recorded the dialog with a boom mic, but they don't want to do ADR, and it's pretty staticy sounding, which makes me think they used just the camera mic. Would Waves C4 do the job?

Comment: It could help to an extent, assuming you solved the distortion issue first.  This may help: http://www.stavrosound.com/blog/wordpress/2011/07/dialogue-clean-out-the-noise/

Comment: On the topic of QT Pro, I cannot recommend it enough.  It's saved me a lot.  It opens a variety of options that can really help troubleshoot QT pix (such as viewing metadata about, extracting, multiplexed audio/video streams within the QT container formats)  and manipulate it as necessary in addition to exporting formats.  Has been a real life saver and the $30 has paid for itself many times over.

Comment: @Stavrosound Thanks so much man. That post helped a lot! 

Comment: @Mitchell Scott Judging by the waveform it looks like they used a camera with auto-gain. Hope the dialogue still ends up being useable!

Comment: @Mitchell Scott Sure thing!  Glad it could be of help!  Have used the C4 for this purpose for a long time and it's my favorite weapon o choice ;)  Couldn't help but notice via your site/resume that you literally live down the road from me.  Too funny!